# Second MPI_Send is hanging if buffer size is over 256

Tags: c, mpi

```
int n, j, i, i2, i3, rank, size,  rowChunk,  **cells, **cellChunk;


MPI_Status status;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);


if(!rank){
    printf("\nEnter board size:\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("\nEnter the total iterations to play:\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &j);


    srand(3);

    rowChunk = n/size; //how many rows each process will get

    for(i=1; i<size; i++){

        MPI_Send(&n,1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&j,1, MPI_INT, i, 7, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    cells = (int**) malloc(n*sizeof(int*));    //create main 2D array

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){

        cells[i] = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(i2=0; i2<n; i2++){           //fill array with random data

            cells[i][i2] = rand() % 2;
        }
    }       

    for(i=1; i<size; i++){        //send blocks of rows to each process
        for(i2=0; i2<rowChunk; i2++){ //this works for all n

            MPI_Send(cells[i2+(rowChunk*i)], n, MPI_INT, i, i2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }

    cellChunk = (int**) malloc(rowChunk*sizeof(int*));

    for(i=0; i<rowChunk; i++){    //declare 2D array for process zero's array chunk

        cellChunk[i] = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    }

    for(i=0; i<rowChunk; i++){   //give process zero it's proper chunk of the array
        for(i2=0; i2<n; i2++){

            cellChunk[i][i2] = cells[i][i2];
        }
    }


    for(i3=1; i3<=j; i3++){

        MPI_Send(cellChunk[0], n, MPI_INT, size-1,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD); //Hangs here if n >256
        MPI_Send(cellChunk[rowChunk-1], n, MPI_INT, 1,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD); //also hangs if n > 256

            ... //Leaving out code that works
```

This code works perfectly if n (array size) is less than or equal to 256. Any greater, and it hangs on the first MPI_Send. Also, when sending out the array row chunks to the other processes, (first MPI_Send) the other processes receive their data perfectly, even though n > 256. What would cause just this MPI_Send to hang if the buffer size is over 256?

Comment: Can you post the full code? I dont see any problems with the snippet you posted.

Answer (score 6):

You are never receiving any messages, and so the code will fill the local MPI buffer space and then deadlock waiting for an `MPI_Recv` (or similar) call to be run.  You will need to insert receive operations so that your messages will actually be sent and processed on the receivers.

Comment: The code is incomplete. MPI_Send is called only by the root. He left out the rest of the code as you can see in the last line. You may want to rephrase your answer.

Answer (score 1):

MPI_Send is a blocking call.  The standard mandates that MPI_Send can return control as early as the message buffer can be safely modified.  Alternatively, the MPI_Send can wait to return until some time AFTER the MPI_Recv has started or completed.

The implementation of MPI you are using is likely doing an "eager" message progression if the message is <256 count (With an MPI_INT datatype, this would be a 1k message).  The message is copied into another buffer and control is returned "early."  For large(r) messages, the MPI_Send call does not return until (at least) the matching MPI_Recv call is executed.

If you post a complete reproducer, you will likely get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

`MPI_Send` "may block until the message is received.", so it is most likely that the matching receive is not reached. You need to make sure the `MPI_Recv`s are placed in the right order. Since you did not post your receive part, it is impossible to tell the details.

You could restructure your application, to make sure the matching receives are in order. It also might be convenient for you to use the combined `MPI_Sendrecv` or the nonblocking `MPI_Isend`, `MPI_Irecv` and `MPI_Wait`.